# A coords image - form over an image

Tags: html, image, forms

I would like to put 2 forms over an image

How can I do this?

Comment: tried to replace the href code from this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap with the form codes..

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: *sidenote:* w3schools is full of incorrect information. be careful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the forms in a `div`. Give to the `div` a `background-image`.